# retrieve information from html using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I would like to retrieve certain information from html using Jsoup.

These are the items I'd like to retrieve:

```
<td class="text" nowrap valign="top">&#x2022; 2012年05月14-23日</td>
<td class="text" valign="top"><a href="/events/2012/1205142301.pdf" target="new" class="text">北京、湖南商务考察团</a></td>
```

I managed to retrieve the 2nd item, which contains a URL and a Chinese title but not the first item. can someone help?

I used the following code to retrieve the 2nd item:

```
Element image = doc.select("td.text a").get(c);
String v = image.attr("href");
url = ("http://www.s-cba.org.sg" + v);
Log.d("url", url);

Element eventName = doc.select("td.text a").get(c);
event = eventName.text();
Log.d("event", event);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Element link = doc.select("td.text a").first();
Element dateTd = link.parent().previousElementSibling();

String url = link.attr("href")
String title = link.text();
String date = dateTd.text();
```